# grep based on first column

Tags: linux, grep

I have a big data file called fileA having the following format

```
col1    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col5    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col3    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col4    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
```

The separator between 1st and 2nd columns is \t. Other separators are comma.
I have another file containing the name of rows I am interested in, called fileB, which looks like:

```
col3
col1
...
```

Both files are not sorted. I want to retrieve all the rows from fileA with names appearing in fileB. The code `grep -f fileB fileA` does this job, but I think it will search all fileds in fileA, which takes long time. How can I specify only to search the 1st column in fileA?

Comment: Have a look at the join command. From there I think you can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join <(sort -t $'\t' -k 1 fileA) <(sort -t $'\t' -k 1 fileB)
```

Files are sorted in O(n.log(n)+p.log(p)) then they're merged in O(n+p), I don't think we can do better than that.

**EDIT** Ok, we can do better with a hash table which will be O(n+p).

Answer (score 0):

linear time O(n) solution without sorting. (I didn't test, hope no typo):

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=7;next}a[$1]' fileB fileA
```

note that the `get` operation on a hashtable is considered as `O(1)`